# Area of mobious strip.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I want to find area of Mobious strip. I found parameterization

$\displaystyle x(s,t) = \left(1 + \frac{t}{2} \cos \frac{s}{2} \right) \cos s$

$\displaystyle y(s,t) = \left(1 + \frac{t}{2} \cos \frac{s}{2} \right) \sin s$

$\displaystyle z(s,y) = \frac{t}{2} \sin \frac{s}{2},$

where $0 \le s < 2 \pi$ and $-1 \le t \le 1$.

Now I want to calculate Jacobian of $(x(s,t), y(s,t), z(s,t))$, but it seems to be a dead end.

Can I ask for some help?

Comment: It's unclear what you're seeking for exactly. The area depends, naturally, on the parametrization. So if you are free to choose a parametrization as you like, the words "area of Moebious band" make no sense. Are you referring to a specific subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ diffeomorphic to the Moebious band?

Comment: I am trying to calculate $ \displaystyle \int_D 1 \mbox{d}x  \mbox{d}y \mbox{d}z$, where D is given by parametrization in first post. Maybe I should not write "area". I'm just curious, is this integral equal to $2 \pi$ or $ 4 \pi$